# Trouble adding font awesome to scene builder(Missing classes)

Tags: javafx, font-awesome, scenebuilder

I recently started my school project containing graphics with JavaFX. I added Font Awsome to maven dependencies and classes are fine loaded in the IntelliJ but when I am added its JAR file to scene builder there are only: 1. GlyphCheckBox and 2. GlyphStack and there isn't any FontAwsomeIconView in it.
How should I fix this problem? (I'm using JDK 13, JavaFX 14 and scene builder 11)

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>de.jensd</groupId>
            <artifactId>fontawesomefx</artifactId>
            <version>8.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of [FontAwesomeFX](https://bitbucket.org/Jerady/fontawesomefx/src/master/) (11) is hosted at [bintray](https://bintray.com/jerady/maven/FontAwesomeFX/view); the one in maven central (8.9) is not compatible with the the latest JDK because of some old com.sun references in the code.

- Open the JAR/FXML Manager in SceneBuilder (dropdown menu in the Library pane)
- Add a repository with the URL - https://dl.bintray.com/jerady/maven/
- Then you have to add de.jensd:fontawesomefx-commons:11.0 as well as de.jensd.fontawesomefx-fontawesome:4.7.0-11 to get FontAwesomeIconView to show up in the controls list.

Comment: how should I solve the problem? isn't there any way I can use the library?

Comment: Updated the answer with a few steps - mostly the issue is on the developer not updating the project in the main repositories